# How to 410 all urls with .html extension in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-410

I want to 410 all urls with .html extension.

say xx.html, yy.html (all with .html).

How do I acheive that with htacess Rewrite or redirect 410 rules?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status `410` means "Gone", which can be accomplished by the `[G]` flag in mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteRule \.html$ - [G]
```

See [documentation for the G flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_g) and the [documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Not sure. Getting 500 error. I am using <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
could you give me the complete code?

Comment: @HelenM since you mention .htaccess I assume some sort of Apache server. In which case, you should check the _error_ log while trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this single line to your .htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch gone "/*\.html$"
```

Done, this is auto http header status to 410

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.html$ - [G]
```